# If the union of two languages is NP-complete, is one of them NP-complete?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability

**Question 1)** If $A\cup B$ is NP-complete, and $A$ is NP, and $B$ is P, then is $A$ NP-complete?

I don't think so but I am unsure. When I try to reduce $A\cup B$ to $A$, I fail because strings in $B$ cannot be decided by a decider for $A$.

**Question 2)** On the other hand, given $A$ is NP-complete, and $B$ is P, then is $A\cup B$ NP-complete?

Comment: The intersection of two languages can be NP-complete even if both languages are in P.

Comment: $\cup$ is the symbol for union, not intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test whether a string is in $A \cup B$, first test (in polynomial time) whether it is in $B$.  If it isn't, you use the $A$-decider to test whether it is in $A$.

For your second problem: what happens if $B$ accepts everything?

Comment: I understand the answer to my second question, but I don't understand the answer to my first question. Can you explain how your solution to my first question implies that $A$ is NP-complete?

Comment: $A \cup B$ is NP-complete, so any problem in NP can be reduced in polynomial time to $A \cup B$.  But $A \cup B$ can be  reduced in polynomial time to $A$.  You already assumed $A$ is in NP.

Comment: Is it possible to give a many-one reduction from $A\cup B$ to $A$? I think this is where I went wrong. I didn't know that it was okay to show NP-completeness using reductions other than many-one reductions.

Comment: Let $a$ be a string that is in $A$.  To test whether
string $s \in A \cup B$, first test (in polynomial time) whether $s \in B$.  If it is, let $t = a$, otherwise let $t=s$.  Then $s \in A \cup B$ iff $t \in A$.  This is a many-one reduction.